# Understanding the definition of enthalpy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, enthalpy

My chemistry text describes Internal Energy (U) of a substance as the sum of all categories of energy, i.e., Kinetic (temperature), potential, bonding, etc.

Then, Enthalpy is defined as:

$$H=U+PV$$

But, it seems to me that $PV$ (pressure x volume) is a form of potential energy, even though $U$ presumably already includes potential energy. Why does it look as though potential energy is being included twice?

Comment: When in doubts about statements or explanations of lectures or textbooks, always try first to verify the facts in independent available offline or online sources, before you decide to ask. 
// This way you prevent creation of redundant info  if existing answer or info could be easily found.

Comment: Funny fact: Gas expansion work is not release of gas potential energy,but it is conversion of kinetic energy, at least for monoatomic gases. (Or of mostly kinetic energy for other gases.)

Comment: In my judgment, trying to assign a physical interpretation to enthalpy is a waste of your valuable time.  Enthalpy is just a convenient shorthand parameter of U and PV to work with in solving many kinds of thermodynamics problems.

Comment: @ChetMiller You could have linked to your earlier answer, instead of repeating yourself. I don't see any problem with interpretation. U is a property of an object itself and PV is a correction for pressure, ambient, or otherwise, that adds up to U.

Comment: @Mithoron I didn't know how to look up my previous answer.

Comment: Umm, it was linked right there, in related / https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49701/enthalpy-change-vs-change-in-internal-energy-in-a-system now is linked thrice ;)

Answer (score 1):

> But, it seems to me that PV
> (pressure x volume) is a form of potential energy, even though U
> presumably already includes potential energy. Why does it look as though potential energy is being included twice?

PV is the work you have to do on the surrounding if you start with a volume of zero and expand it reversibly to the volume of the system V. The reason we add it is for convenience, and once we add this term, the value no longer reflects the inner energy, but something new called enthalpy. While the meaning of enthalpy is less clear than that of internal energy, it turns out to be useful nonetheless.

Specifically, the change in enthalpy $\Delta$H happens to be equal to the heat exchange under certain conditions (same temperature and pressure before and after, no work except for expansion work p $\Delta$V).